# Python: deepcopy(list) vs new_list = old_list[:]

Tags: python, list, copy

I'm doing exercise #9 from http://openbookproject.net/thinkcs/python/english2e/ch09.html and have ran into something that doesn't make sense.

The exercise suggests using `copy.deepcopy()` to make my task easier but I don't see how it could.

```
def add_row(matrix):
    """
        >>> m = [[0, 0], [0, 0]]
        >>> add_row(m)
        [[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]]
        >>> n = [[3, 2, 5], [1, 4, 7]]
        >>> add_row(n)
        [[3, 2, 5], [1, 4, 7], [0, 0, 0]]
        >>> n
        [[3, 2, 5], [1, 4, 7]]
    """

    import copy
    # final = copy.deepcopy(matrix)  # first way
    final = matrix[:]                # second way
    li = []
    for i in range(len(matrix[0])):
        li.append(0)
    # return final.append(li)  # why doesn't this work?
    final.append(li)            # but this does
    return final
```

I'm confused why the book suggests using `deepcopy()` when a simple `list[:]` copies it. Am I using it wrong? Is my function completely out of wack?

I also have some confusion returning values. the question is documents in the code above.

TIA

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You asked two questions:

#### Deep vs. shallow copy

`matrix[:]` is a **shallow copy** -- it only copies the elements directly stored in it, and doesn't recursively duplicate the elements of arrays or other references within itself. That means:

```
a = [[4]]
b = a[:]
a[0].append(5)
print b[0] # Outputs [4, 5], as a[0] and b[0] point to the same array
```

The same would happen if you stored an object in `a`.

`deepcopy()` is, naturally, a **deep copy** -- it makes copies of each of its elements recursively, all the way down the tree:

```
a = [[4]]
c = copy.deepcopy(a)
a[0].append(5)
print c[0] # Outputs [4], as c[0] is a copy of the elements of a[0] into a new array
```

#### Returning

`return final.append(li)` is different from calling `append` and returning `final` because list.append does not return the list object itself, it returns `None`

Answer (score 2):

See the [documentation on deep and shallow copy](http://docs.python.org/library/copy.html).

```
list[:]
```

does not create copies of nested elements.

For your problem regarding the return statement, it looks like you're not inside a function when you call it, I assume that happened while pasting the code here. Regarding the return value Michael Mrozek is right.

Comment: thanks.  this further cleared it up for me and had to do it in the console to see it myself.